# LDT and Paging in Linux for X86 processors

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to understand the use of LDT when the system supports paging.

My understanding:

- GDT has segments for user CS & DS and kernel CS and DS.
- GDT is shared by all the processes while LDT is local to each process.
- LDT was used to implement protection ie. ( To prevent one process accessing code/data of another process. )
- Linux currently has a default LDT which is shared by all the processes similar to GDT.
- TLS was previously implemented by creating an entry in LDT. This limited the number of threads in an application to 8192. This was improved by having a TLS in GDT. On a context switch, the TLS entry on the GDT points to the segment local to the thread.
- Finally, paging is used to ensure that different process has there own code and data section by mapping the same linear address of different processes into different physical pages.

With this, what's the use of a LDT in linux ? Why do we even have one which is shared by all the process ?

Comment: I think because the hardware multitasking mechanism requires it, just like one TSS is requiredn, Linux only uses one and shares it for all processes.